# My Java program seems to get...stuck (?) at a point during execution. I'm baffled.

Tags: java, methods, driver, java.util.scanner

So, I'm trying to create a driver for my method. I apologize in advance, I know very little about what I'm talking about. What the program does, is it calculates sine, cosine, and the exponential function by means of taylor series for a number that the user inputs. The use of Math.pow and Math.fact were not allowed. My compiler isn't giving me any errors, and I'm all out of ideas at this point. In addition, the scanner doesn't seem to stop accepting input after I press enter. It continues to take numbers, but doesn't do anything else. It gives an exception when I type a letter. High possibility of ID10T error. I know that the output isn't well formatted yet, but that's because I haven't had a chance to see it yet. If someone could help me figure this out, I would be very greatful. Thanks in advance!

-An aspiring code monkey

Driver (Lab4.java)

```
/*
  This program is being created to solve Lab 4.
*/
import java.util.*;
public class Lab4
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String again, more = "y";

    while (more.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'Y')
    {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Input X: ");

         Function number = new Function();
           double x = number.x();
           System.out.println("x = " + x);

         Function sine = new Function();         
            double mySin = sine.funcSine();

         Function cosine = new Function();
            double myCos = cosine.funcCos();

         Function expo = new Function();      
            double myExp = expo.funcExp();   

     System.out.println("\t\t\t\tLibraryResult       My Result");
     System.out.println("\n\t\tsin("  + Function.x() + ")" + " = " + "\t\t\t" + Math.sin(Function.x()) + "\t" + mySin);  
     System.out.println("\n\t\tcos("  + Function.x() + ")" + " = " + "\t\t\t" + Math.cos(Function.x()) + "\t" + myCos); 
     System.out.println("\n\t\texp("  + Function.x() + ")" + " = " + "\t\t\t" + Math.exp(Function.x()) + "\t" + myExp);
     System.out.println("\n\t\t\tDo more (Y/N) ? ");
     more = keyboard.next();
     String junk = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Method (Function.java)

```
/*
  This class provides the information for the parent to use in order to solve Lab 4.
*/


import java.util.*;
public class Function
{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       public static int number;
       private double temp = 1;
       private double last = 1;


    public static double x()
    {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      double x = keyboard.nextDouble();
      return x;
    }  

    public static double pow(double value, double power)
    {
       if(power == 0)
       {
          return 1;
       }
         double result = value;
         for(int i = 0; i < power -1; i++)
       {
          result = result * value; 
       }
       return result;
    }

    public static double getFact()
    {
       while (number < 0)
       {
           number =(number * -1);
       } 
       double factorial = 1;
       if (0 == (number % 1))
       {
          do
          {
             factorial = factorial * number;
             --number;

          } while (number >= 1);

       }
       else     //Stirling's Approximation
        {
           double e = 2.718281828459;
           double part1 = Math.sqrt(2 * 3.141592653589 * number);
           double part2a = (number / e);
           double part2b = (pow(part2a,number));
           factorial = (part1 * part2b);
        }
            return factorial;
    }

    public static double funcSine()
    {
        int place = 0;  
        double next = x()*1;
        for(number = 3; number <= 30; number = number + 2)
        {                    
           next = next + ((pow((-1),place))*((pow(x(),number))/(getFact())));
           place = place + 1;
        }
        double mySin = next * 1;
        return mySin;
    }

    public static double funcCos()
    {
      int place = 0;
      double next = 1;
      for(number = 2; number <= 30; number = number + 2)
      {
         next = next + ((pow(-1,place))*((pow(x(),number))/(getFact())));
         place = place + 1;
      }
      double myCos = next * 1;
      return myCos;
    }
    public static double funcExp()
    {
       int place = 0;
       double next = 1 + x();
       for(number = 1; number <= 30; number++)
       {
          next = next + ((pow(-1,place))*((pow(x(),number))/(getFact())));
          place = place + 1; 
       }
       double myExp = next * 1;
       return myExp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger. This will save you countless hours in the long run.

Comment: I attempted debugging, and got nowhere fast. No amount of google-fu helped me solve the message I was getting. Shortly thereafter, the debugger decided to completely ignore my breakpoints. It just immediately skips to the end. I'm about to pull  my hair out over this. I just can't figure out why it doesn't want to move on past entering X.

Comment: Random tip: When you're tossing input, you don't need to save it to a variable. Just call the method without assigning it to anything, and it will do the same thing, without the memory allocation/deallocation overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Check the syntax of your while loop:

```
 while (more.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'Y')
```

Think about when the program will ever not satisfy this expression.

Also you have multiple Scanners all over your code. ITs not clear why you need to keep reading inout over and over again.

Comment: I appreciate the responses, guys!

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a hint. Answer the question for the asker, explaining *why* it won't work -- which might well, unless I missed something.

Comment: Give a someone a fish in all that.  Also its quite clear that the code is reading input in main once, then again on creation of the Function class then again when using the static method x in  the Function class. Then another 3 times when instantiating Function repeatedly. So it's no wonder the code is continuously looking for user input. Frankly there are several errors in this code. I would rather help them to think what they are doing. Even if this is 'strictly' a Q&A site. Why don't you let the moderators decide the quality of my answer. They can delete the entire thread if they wish